# Displaying an HTML error page in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, exception

I would like to display an `HTML` error page when I catch a certain exception in my `ASP.NET Core` project. The page is stored in the project's root and I'm having trouble finding what I need to use in order to show this page. in this case, the application is already running and I would like the exception to be handled by redirecting the URL to the internally contained `.html` page.
What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Glad to clarify anything if needed, I'm very new to coding in general and I'll try my best to elaborate.

Comment: Hi @Flats, Did you want to display a custom error page?

Comment: @Rena Yes, I would like to display a custom page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute custom error page,you could use `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` and `UseExceptionHandler` middleware like below:

Controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    [Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
    public IActionResult StatusCodeError(int statusCode)
    {
        return Redirect("Index.html");  //Index.html located in wwwroot folder
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{

    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error handling is built into ASP.NET Core. This [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0) provides the overview.

The important bits are to configure the error handler within `Configure` method of `Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

Then have a Razor page called `Error.cshtml` that handles and displays whatever content you'd like.

Comment: OP said: "I would like to display an HTML error page when I catch a certain exception" your solution catch all exceptions and return Http 500.