# C# Asp.Net MVC Core - Why does my ErrorController never use the HttpStatusCodeHandler action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, error-handling

I have a C# Asp.Net MVC Core (.Net 8.0) web application.

I have built an ErrorController to handle any error status codes that occur, as follows:

public class ErrorController : Controller
{
private readonly ILogger _logger;

```
public ErrorController(ILogger<ErrorController> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[Route("/Error/{statusCode}")]
public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
{
    var statusCodeResult = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

    switch (statusCode)
    {
        case 400:
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Bad Request. The server could not understand the request.";
            _logger.LogWarning($"400 Error Occurred. Path = {statusCodeResult.OriginalPath}" +
                               $" and QueryString = {statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString}");
            break;

        case 401:
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Unauthorized. You are not authorized to access the requested resource.";
            _logger.LogWarning($"401 Error Occurred. Path = {statusCodeResult.OriginalPath}" +
                               $" and QueryString = {statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString}");
            break;

        case 403:
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Forbidden. You do not have permission to access the requested resource.";
            _logger.LogWarning($"403 Error Occurred. Path = {statusCodeResult.OriginalPath}" +
                               $" and QueryString = {statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString}");
            break;

        case 404:
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Not Found. The resource you requested could not be found.";
            _logger.LogWarning($"404 Error Occurred. Path = {statusCodeResult.OriginalPath}" +
                               $" and QueryString = {statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString}");
            break;

        case 500:
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Internal Server Error. An unexpected error occurred on the server.";
            _logger.LogError($"500 Error Occurred. Path = {statusCodeResult.OriginalPath}" +
                             $" and QueryString = {statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString}");
            break;

        default:
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "An error occurred while processing your request.";
            _logger.LogError($"Error {statusCode} occurred. Path = {statusCodeResult.OriginalPath}" +
                             $" and QueryString = {statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString}");
            break;
    }

    return View("Error");
}

[Route("/Error")]
public IActionResult ErrorHandler()
{
    var statusCodeResult = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();

    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry, an error occurred.";
    _logger.LogError($"Error occurred. Path = {statusCodeResult.OriginalPath}" +
                             $" and QueryString = {statusCodeResult.OriginalQueryString}");

    return View("Error");
}
```

}

However, the action "HttpStatusCodeHandler" never gets called, and I don't understand why? (Every error just ends up in the other action called "ErrorHandler"?

Here is my error handling configuration in my Program.cs file also:

```
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Here is my endpoint configuration code:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "error",
        pattern: "/Error/{statusCode}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "HttpStatusCodeHandler" }
    );

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

});

Any help would be greatly appreciated? Thank you

Comment: Try remove the first slash "/" from the route attribute and conventional route `pattern`. Error/{statusCode}

Comment: Unfortunately the HttpStatusCodeHandler still doesn't get called...

Comment: I've found that if I comment out the ErrorHandler() action, (but keep the HttpStatusCodeHandler() action), then the HttpStatusCodeHandler action gets called every time...

Comment: Hi @Goober, Actually no need add the ErrorHandler action, and you need change `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");` to `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");`, Refer to this case:https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095516/11398810.